# Chrome Extension open popup relative to current window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that will pop up a new window in a position relative to the recently focused window.  I don't think I'm using the `chrome.windows.getCurrent` or `chrome.windows.getLastFocused` methods properly to do this.  Every time I do, I get an `undefined` alert when I try to show a property of that window.

In my `background.js` file, I have:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(showPopup);
function showPopup() {
  var left = chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (w) {
    w.left - 200; 
    // also tried: return w.left - 200;
  });
  alert(left); // undefined
}
```

Reading the [chrome.windows API docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html) left me confused on how to actually return an attribute of a window.  Can anyone shed some light here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's another (or better) way to do this, but I got this to work:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(getCurrentInfo);
function getCurrentInfo() {
  chrome.windows.getCurrent(showPopup);
}
function showPopup(win) {
  alert(win.left); // correct pixel count from left
}
```

My original attempt was wrong because I was trying to return a value from the `get()` callback function and place that into a variable.  This, essentially evaluated to `var left = chrome.windows.get(winId, 790)`, which is an invalid function call.  Rather than that, my call to `chrome.windows.create()` needed to be **inside** the callback function.

Also, a miss before was that the click listener calls a function with a `tab` parameter, not a `window` parameter.  So I needed the `getCurrentInfo()` function to pass in a `tab` and then `chrome.windows.getCurrent()` to pass in window info.